# Getting incorrectly encoded characters when retrieving values from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm encoding all my files in UTF-8 without BOM.

All characters appear correctly when displaying my page, yet values retrieved from my MySQL database such as Árbol render Ás and nont ANSI characters incorrectly (as a black romboid). I'm storing values in database with PHP My Admin manually.

What can be causing this issue with the database? Are there any changes I must do to make the database "utf8-ready"?

Comment: How did you configure your connection in phpMyAdmin? How are the tables defined (default collation)??

Comment: Everything is by default, I just created the table and started inserting rows.

Comment: If tables are created to default (latin1, perhaps?), maybe the data there is encoded to latin1 (iso-8859-1). Check the tables definition thru phpMyAdmin (generate the create table sentence and check at the bottom, ***default=???**). If happens to be something different from utf8, your data is and will be encoded latin1 even if you alter table definition

Comment: I already fixed the problem. The answer was to add the line: ` mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` I'm answering when it becomes available

Comment: And my answer was no help at all, huh?

Comment: Sorry, latin1 was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you connect to the server, use the following command to view your current `client characterset`:

```
status;
```

To set it, use the following command:

```
set names utf8;
```