# Can't store UTF-8 Content in MySQL Using Java PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, jdbc, utf-8

For some strange reason I can't seem to add UTF-8 data to my MySQL database.  When I enter a non-latin character, it's stored as ?????.  Everything else is stored fine.  So for example, "this is an example®™" is stored fine, but "和英辞典" is stored as "????".

The connection url is fine:

```
private DataSource getDB() throws PropertyVetoException {
    ComboPooledDataSource db = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    db.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    db.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://domain.com:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
    db.setUser("...");
    db.setPassword("...");
    return db;
}
```

I'm using PreparedStatement as you would expect, I even tried entering "set names utf8" as someone suggested.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = db.getConnection();

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("set names utf8");
        stmt.execute();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("set character set utf8");
        stmt.execute();

                    ... set title...
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table (title) VALUES (?)");
        stmt.setString(1,title);

        stmt.execute();
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
    ...
```

The table itself seems to be fine.

```
Default Character Set: utf8
Default Collation: utf8_general_ci
...
Field title:
Type text
Character Set: utf8
Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I tested it by entering in Unicode ("和英辞典" specifically) through a GUI editor and then selecting from the table -- and it was returned just fine.  So this seems to be an issue with JDBC.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `title` has the right content? Maybe you read it from a file using ISO-whatever?

Comment: Yes, when I put a breakpoint on title I can see that it's indeed unicode (ex: 和英辞典) and not ????

Comment: `utf8` is a string, so enclose it in quotes like : `"set names 'utf8'"`. Don't mess with the character set.

Comment: @nostromo : What version of the connector are you using?

Comment: adding `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` works for me. My database is already using UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is 2 points in the mysql server to check in order to correctly set the UTF-8 charset.

**Database Level**

This is obtained by creating it :

```
CREATE DATABASE 'db' CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

**Table Level**

All of the tables need to be in UTF-8 also (which seems to be the case for you)

```
CREATE TABLE  `Table1` (
    [...]
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

The important part being **DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci**

Finally, if your code weren't handling utf8 correctly, you could have forced your JVM to use utf8 encoding by changing the settings by on startup :

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 [...]
```

or changing the environment variable

```
"**JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS**" to -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

or programmatically by using :

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding" , "UTF-8");
```

(this last one may not have the desire effect since the JVM caches value of default character encoding on startup)

Hope that helped.

Comment: setting the default encoding for the jvm is useful for some things, but certainly not required to get unicode data into and out of a database.

Comment: based on nostromo's comment yesterday about the breakpoint. We can assume that his jvm is already handling unicode correctly, so I agree that it's not required in his case.

Comment: There's actually three levels. There's also the connection level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283575/getting-incorrectly-encoded-characters-when-retrieving-values-from-mysql-db

Comment: Thanks for the help!  My temporary work around was to store the String columns as binary, and then to change the column to string after all the data had been transfered -- which worked.  However, this isn't a long-term solution -- and now things seem to be working as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On your JDBC connection string, you just need set the charset encoding like this:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8

Answer (score 3):

Use `stmt.setNString(...)` instead of `stmt.setString(...)`.
Also don't forget to check column collation in database side.

Comment: You save my day.

Answer (score 1):

If you log in to your mysql database and run `show variables like 'character%';`
this might provide some insight.

Since you're getting a one-to-one ratio of multi-byte characters to question marks then it's likely that the connection is doing a character set conversion and replacing the Chinese characters with the replacement character for the single-byte set.

Answer (score 0):

Also check locale -a on ubuntu default Ubuntu works with en_us locale and doesn't have other locale installed.
must specify characterEncoding=utf8 while connecting through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

add at the end of your DB connection url - (nothing else needed)
ex.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8
```