# Java, JDBC executeQuery with no result but gets result when running statement myself

Tags: java, mysql, select, jdbc

I have a table named "statuses" in my MySQL database which looks like this:

```
| "id" (int) | "text" varchar(50) | "hex_color" varchar(10) |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | EJ PÅBÖRJAD        | #FF3300                 |
| 2          | ARBETE PÅGÅR       | #FFFF00                 |
| 3          | AVVAKTAR           | #80F0FF                 |
| 4          | ÅTGÄRDAD           | #6DE37A                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's my JDBC Java-code:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(statement);

while(rs.next()){
   Long pid = rs.getLong(1);
   String ptext = rs.getString(2);
   String hex_color = rs.getString(3);

   status = new Statuses(pid, ptext, hex_color);
}
```

When `statement` is:

`SELECT id, text, hex_color FROM statuses WHERE text = 'EJ PÅBÖRJAD'` - 1 result

`SELECT id, text, hex_color FROM statuses WHERE text = 'ARBETE PÅGÅR'` - 0 result

`SELECT id, text, hex_color FROM statuses WHERE text = 'AVVAKTAR'` - 1 result

`SELECT id, text, hex_color FROM statuses WHERE text = 'ÅTGÄRDAD'` - 1 result

**why do i get 0 result on the second statement?**
when i'm running it myself in "mysql command line" i get 1 result!
i've checked that i'm using the same charset (UTF-8) which rules out charset problem.

**can someone please help me on this matter?**

kind regards, Clyde

Comment: Try printing the statements before executing them in the code.
that may help you to debug

Comment: I've already done that. It says `SELECT id, text, hex_color FROM statuses WHERE text = 'ARBETE PÅGÅR'` before it executes

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625808/cant-store-utf-8-content-in-mysql-using-java-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 1):

Are you absoluty sure that

- you haven't made a copy-paste error for `'ARBETE PÅGÅR'` or
- the database contains an extra space or other unprintable character in/after `'ARBETE PÅGÅR'`

Try surrounding with wildcards, eg. `SELECT * FROM statuses WHERE text LIKE '%ARBETE%PÅGÅR%'` and see if that makes a difference?

Cheers,

Comment: The statement is genereted by the website. all i'm doing is copying the generated statement which fails, running it myself and i get 1 result. wildcards doesn't work either. screw swedish, i'll change the status text to english instead. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a 7 months old post but I thinks you could check if you have committed after you inserted those rows.

When you run the query yourself, you are probably using the same session that you used to insert those rows. That's why you can see them.
Until you commit, other users won't be able to see the effect(of the inserts).