# Unable to insert utf-8 chars with prepared statement to mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have problem insert utf-8 chars with preparred statement like this:

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tournament_system?"
            + "user=root&password=root");

    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn
            .prepareStatement("  insert into PLAYER (ID, NAME, SURNAME, CLUB,  WORLD_RANKING, USER_ID)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?,  ?, ?)");
    ps.setInt(1, 100001);
    ps.setString(2, "ěščřž");
    ps.setString(3, "xxx");
    ps.setString(4, null);
    ps.setInt(5, 5);
    ps.setInt(6, 1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

it insert into column name just this: "?š??ž"

but when I execute sql in phpMyAdmin like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tournament_system`.`PLAYER` (`ID`, `NAME`, `SURNAME`, `CLUB`, `PLAYER_DISCRIMINATOR`, `WORLD_RANKING`, `USER_ID`) VALUES ('10002', 'ěščřž', 'qqq', NULL, 'qqq', NULL, '1');
```

it works good

so where is the problem ? I think I have configured my db right if second option works

MYSQL Version:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.10.1
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**UPDATED:**

when I tried this:         `ps.setBytes(2, "ččřž".getBytes("UTF-8"));`
then it works but I really cant change all my ps to this. How to solve it otherwise ?

Comment: Do you have your string literal just like that in your Java source code? Is it possible that actually the problem is in the settings you use to compile the code? I would suggest that you log the Unicode values of the string - it may be nothing to do with the database.

Comment: Try this, hope this will help you.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647139/2189457)

Comment: Is it not the problem with the encoding of your java source file? Do you use UTF-8 in your editor setting?

Comment: Yes I think I am using utf-8 encoding. Raj: I try your link to set system encoding but also with no success. Jon: How I can log Unicode values ?

Comment: Set the encoding in the connection string, also, make sure the column is utf8 type.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the encoding to your jdbc connection string with `characterEncoding=UTF-8`, which will take effect on the `PreparedStatement`:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tournament_system?"
        + "user=root&password=root&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
```